# ng model is not working even after importing forms module in app.module.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngmodel

Here is the attached screenshot where you can see that `FormsModule` is imported in `app.module.ts` file but still the error haven't resolved

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is the `login component` and screenshot is posted given below
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcfq4.png

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open app.module.ts and add the import line

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And add FormsModule to imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
})
```

And i could see that you have forgot to declare your LoginComponent!

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
})
```

Comment: I think this is a correct answer. Try to use this.